# Get Date when a User added to a Active Directory Group - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, active-directory

Example:

I have few Groups in Active Directory:

1. Admin Group
2. SOft Group
3. Net group

And few users like:

- Test1
- Test2
- Test3

The `Test1` user is a member of all 3 groups.

I want to find out when `Test1` user was added to group Admin Group.

Comment: Please do share what you have tried so far.. Maybe some codes

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at msds-replvaluemetadata attribute. The attribute stores all group members with date and domain controller where the change occurred. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/pie/2014/08/25/metadata-2-the-ephemeral-admin-or-how-to-track-the-group-membership/